# User authenication being lost on remoting call

Tags: authentication, service

My administration page and webpart make calls to a service via .Net remoting.

I've added AD credential checking to the service and discovered that the calls being made from both the admin page and the web part are coming thru as "NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON" instead of the logged-on user.

As a test, I've written a WinForms application that makes the same calls and the service is correctly figuring out the credentials.

So....is there some special code that I can add to my SharePoint code to get the correct username attached to the thread making the calls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume the service is running on a seperate server? It sounds like uou are running into the classic "double hop" issue with authentication.

Here is one (of many) blog posts that describes the double-hop authentication issue.

[Double-hop authentication: Why NTLM fails and Kerberos works](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/besidethepoint/double-hop-authentication-why-ntlm-fails-and-kerberos-works)

You have 3 choices:

- Configure Kerberos (doable)
- Configure Claims and re-instrument your .NET remoting service to support claims (complicated)
- Use the [Secure Store Service](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/ee557754%28v=office.14%29) and configure single sign-on

Comment: Thanks Chris, I had COMPLETELY forgotten about the double-hop problem.  I ran the service on the SharePoint server and the problem went away.